# Sum quantities for list of items in shopping cart using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, shopping-cart

I'm trying to write a small piece of Javascript that will sort through a list of items in a shopping cart and determine whether the quantities for each brand sum to a multiple of **12**.

An example of the shopping cart would be:

```
 - Brand 1 - Oranges ---------- Qty: 10
 - Brand 2 - Oranges ---------- Qty: 4
 - Brand 1 - Oranges ---------- Qty: 2
 - Brand 3 - Oranges ---------- Qty: 6
 - Brand 2 - Oranges ---------- Qty: 20
```

The totals are therefore: `Brand 1 = 12`, `Brand 2 = 24`, `Brand 3 = 6`.

If the total of `Brand 1`, `Brand 2` or `Brand 3` is not a multiple of **12** (eg. `Brand 3` above), I want the Javascript function to produce an error.

I think the best way to solve this is through an array and somehow splitting it based on brand then summing the totals but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are the items in your shopping cart plain strings? If so you really should try to use objects there. Then it's just a matter of lopping through the objects and creating a new object with the brand counts and using `% 12 == 0` (modulo) on them.

Comment: @JasperdeVries Thanks for the reply. I think it's all working now. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two loops for that, the first one is to sum up all the qty's for each brand, the 2nd loop is to check if all sums are a multiple of 12.

You can find an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/5QGWG/

Comment: That's great, thanks Mark. What would be the best way to build the array of brands and quantities dynamically using html on the screen. I've got the following so far:
`$(".brand-name").each(function(){
  cart.push('brand:'+($(this).text())+',qty:'+$('.quantity'));
});`

Comment: What about `cart.push({ brand: $(this).text(), qty: $('.quantity') });`, so you have an array of hashes, which will be easier to access.

Comment: I just worked that out; I originally didn't have the items set up as objects so the above `push` code works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help. I love stackoverflow!